# Excel Range Editing

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Hi I have a range in a cell made up by a formula resulting in "F1:F3".
I want to know how can I put this range into a new formula example:

=STDEV.P('SÉRIE 0516'!XXXXX)*SQRT(252)

Where on the XXXX should be the range on that cell "F1:F3" resulted by a formula.

My final resultu should be a formula:
=STDEV.P('SÉRIE 0516'!F1:F3)*SQRT(252)

Comment: use indirect, but there may be a better way, how are you coming up with `F1:F3` what is the formula?

Comment: ="F"&VLOOKUP("M-1 Ini";I48:M59;3;0)&":F"&VLOOKUP("M-1 Fim";I48:M59;3;0)

Comment: Those vlookups return the line position

Comment: you are doing a vlookup on two rows, are the locations set, is `M-1 Ini` in `I48` and `M-1 Fim` in `I49`, or vice versa? Or can their positions be random on those two rows?

Comment: a basic example: youd wrap "F"&VLOOKUP("M-1 Ini";I48:M59;3;0)&":F"&VLOOKUP("M-1 Fim";I48:M59;3;0) in Index. -  index("F"&VLOOKUP("M-1 Ini";I48:M59;3;0)&":F"&VLOOKUP("M-1 Fim";I48:M59;3;0) ,0)  ... & your whole output would be an array , and youd cse the end formula for each result. but if you wanted to sum them all or do somethinhg else with them too, you could do that too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this as a model:

```
=STDEV.P(INDIRECT("'SÉRIE 0516'!" & B1)*SQRT(252))
```

[image]

Here we use cell **B1** as the reference.

Answer (score 2):

Avoid the volatile INDIRECT by using INDEX():

```
=STDEV.P(INDEX('SÉRIE 0516'!$F:$F;$K$48):INDEX('SÉRIE 0516'!$F:$F;$K$49))*SQRT(252)
```

You can replace the `$K$48` and `$K$49` with the vlookups, but I think this will work for you.